# Eclipse version which has BIRT framework by default

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide

Can you please advice which is the latest version of eclipse which has BIRT plugin installed by default.

Answer (score 0):

From [the Eclipse downloads page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) you can select either the **Eclipse IDE for Java and Report Developers** package or use the installer and select that same package when prompted.

By the way, if you want to compare the features that are included in each package, there is a [Compare & Combine Packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/compare.php?release=mars) link on the Downloads page.